# link names in chat using websockets

Tags: javascript, websocket, chat

I am trying to solve this problem where I am using chat tutorial http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/05/chat-using-websocket-php-socket. I am attempting to create anchors that that will go to each users profile if clicked on. The problem is that during testing with multiple users the links only direct to the very first user in the room. I have spent a fair amount of time trying to figure this out.
How do I get separate clickable links?
I am using CodeIgniter with links processed by a controller. I cannot fathom how I would perform any loop or while statements in this structure.

> Javascript with HTML

```
websocket.onmessage = function(ev) {
    var msg = JSON.parse(ev.data); //PHP sends Json data
    var type = msg.type; //message type
    var umsg = msg.message; //message text
    var uname = msg.name; //user name
    var ucolor = msg.color; //color

    if(type == 'usermsg') 
    {
        $('#message_box').append("<div><span class=\'user_name\'       style=\'color:#'+ucolor+'\"><button type='button' class='greenButton' onclick='proceed()' id='mem_name' value='"+uname+"'>"+uname+"</button></span> : <span class=\"user_message\">"+umsg+" </span></div>" );

    }`
```

> JS Function

```
function proceed (button) {
    var mem_name = $('#mem_name').val();
    var form = document.createElement('form');
    form.setAttribute('method', 'post');
    form.setAttribute('action', 'member_chat');
    form.style.display = 'hidden';
    form.setAttribute("target", "formresult");

    var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");      
    hiddenField.setAttribute('name', 'mem_chat');
    hiddenField.setAttribute('value', mem_name)
    form.appendChild(hiddenField);
    document.body.appendChild(form)
    form.submit();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a high level, your issue is that all your inserted buttons have the same id, `mem_name`. IDs must be unique, so `$("#mem_name")` stops after finding the first mafch.

The quick fix here is to pass `this` in your inline click listener:

```
onclick="proceed(this)"
```

And use `$(button)` (i.e., the parameter to `proceed`) instead of `$("#mem_name")`.

A more elegant solution would be to eliminate inline listeners at all and use jQuery's `.on` delegation. Change the `id=mem_name` to `class=mem_name`, eliminate the `onclick` listener, and add this code to run *once only* (i.e., not inside a message event listener):

```
$("#message_box").on("click", ".mem_name", proceed);
```

Then change the `$("#mem_name")` to `$(this)`. This will cause `proceed` to run any time an element with a `mem_name` class is clicked inside of `#message_box`.

Comment: (SOLVED) Thank you so very much. You have saved my marriage and my life. I am over the moon.

Comment: @rbwilkinson Wow, glad I could help! :) To mark the question as resolved, you can [accept this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking the checkmark.